# Исключить из выборки строки с датой больше года назад

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `payments`
WHERE `MEMBER_ID`= 1052
```

нужно исключить записи по полю с датой, если дата больше года назад.
пробовал так:

```
AND (NOW() - PAYMENT_DATE) < 31536000
```

однако такое условие не срабатывает, не выводится ничего, хотя есть даты 2016 года

Comment: PAYMENT_DATE < (NOW() - 31536000)

Comment: Дата в каком формате, календарном?

Comment: да, но когда я пробовал делать SELECT *, NOW() - PAYMENT_DATE то выводилось в timestamp

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev тоже не срабатывает, да и разницы вроде как нет

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `payments`
 WHERE `MEMBER_ID`= 1052
   AND PAYMENT_DATE > now() - interval 1 year
```

Старайтесь любые сравнения писать так, что бы колонки таблицы не были заключены ни в какие функции или математические операции. Старайтесь переставить аргументы выражения так, что бы чистое поле сравнивалось с неким вычисляемым (без использования данных из таблиц) значением. Потому что в таком случае во первых само значение будет вычисляться только один раз, а не для каждой строки заново. Во вторых, если существует подходящий индекс - оптимизатор сможет его использовать.

Answer (score 0):

```
AND DATEFIFF(NOW(), PAYMENT_DATE) < 365
```

Так точно работает в mysql если столбец имеет тип datetime

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать таким образом

```
SELECT * FROM `payments`
WHERE `MEMBER_ID`= 1052 AND (TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(PAYMENT_DATE) <= 365)
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался:

```
 (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(PAYMENT_DATE)) < 31536000
```

NOW() надо приводить к timestamp

Comment: Мой вариант все таки попробуйте, по идее должен работать и он явно оптимальнее по описанным в ответе причинам

Comment: да, видимо он быстрее отработает